# Can't turn on Tunnel Bear VPN on my Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, vpn

I used to be able to to turn on Tunnel Bear VPN on my Galaxy S4. But now, whenever I get the prompt that says `I trust this application`, it won't let me select the check box. So, I can't connect.

Comment: Did you tried clearing the cache and the data stored by the Tunnel bear application?? I would say try going to the settings>application manager>Tap over the tunnel bear app>Clear the Cache and the data stored.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: I had a screen filter on, and for some reason, this was blocking me from hitting accept.

Comment: "for some reason" = security. Malicious apps could use a "screen filter" to overlay something on a button you otherwise would not wish to press (e.g. switching *off* a VPN so they could re-direct you elsewhere). Hence: Overlay active = buttons disabled. So yes, if you had a screen-filter running, this was the most likely cause :) (no critics to your answer, just shipping some explanation ;)